# Read laz files are stored on IBM COS

Tags: python, cloud-gis, pdal

I have a problem with reading laz files that are stored at [IBM cloud object storage](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/object-storage).

I have built [pywren-ibm](https://github.com/pywren/pywren-ibm-cloud) library with all [PDAL](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL) requirements - one of them with docker. I then deploy it to [IBM cloud function as an action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzJ5PzdpqMU), where the error that appear is "Unable to open stream for 'Colorea.laz" with error 'No such file or directory.' How can I read the files with PDAL in cloud function?

Here is some of the code:

```
import pywren_ibm_cloud as pywren
import pdal
import json

def manip_data(bucket, key, data_stream):

        data = data_stream.read()
        cr_json ={
             "pipeline": [
              { 
                  "type": "readers.las",
                  "filename": f"{key}"
              }, 
              {
                  "type":"filters.range",
                  "limits":"Classification[9:9]"
              }

          ]
        }

        consulta = json.dumps(cr_json, indent=4)
        pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json.dumps(cr_json, indent=4))
        pipeline.validate()
        pipeline.loglevel = 8
        n_points = pipeline.execute()

bucketname = 'The bucket name'
pw = pywren.ibm_cf_executor(runtime='ammarokran/pywren-pdal:1.0')
pw.map(manip_data, bucketname, chunk_size=None)
print(pw.get_result())
```

The code is running from local pc with jupyter notebook.